# Graphic card for PCI 3.0 x4

Tags: graphics-cards

I plan to buy an Eizo monitor Flexscan EV2495 that supports resolution 1920x1200. Both for office work (long hours of programming) and occasionally photo editing (Photoshop, Lightroom).

My current PC is rather old and supports a maximum resolution of only 1920x1080. It has an ASRock BT150A-X1 motherboard with a built-in graphic card but still has some free PCI slots, precisely PCIe 3.0 x4.

I'm looking for a low-budget card that I could connect to my motherboard. What would you recommend?

Comment: That board does not have a PCIe x4 port on it at all. You may be mistaken, it looks like you have two 16x slots and three x1 slots. Any PCIe graphics card will work in either of those x16 slots.

Comment: @Romen Thanks. I used SiSoft Sandra report instead of just opening the box or reading the specs.

Comment: Check for intel gfx updates?

Comment: Are U sure it is BT and not B150A-X1 2which - Supports DVI-D with max. resolution up to 1920x1200 @ 60Hz

Comment: It was definitely a limitation of my monitor. I connected the Eizo monitor and there is no problem with 1920x1200 resolution at all.